# SwiftUI - Navigation Link transition is slow when tapping on it

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm developing a SwiftUI App with Xcode 12.0.

My HomeView simply contains a NavigationLink (within a NavigationView)  that push to a second View containing a List of more than 4.000 elements previously downloaded from a server (when tapping the navigation link the download is already completed).

The issue is that when I tap it takes almost 2 seconds to show the next page. The same thing happen when I tap the iOS Back button.

In other hands, doing the same thing without a big List makes it fast as it should always be.

The HomeView Navigation link is this:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
                            ForEach(firstHomeCard) { homeCard in
                                NavigationLink(destination: ExoplanetsDatabaseView()) {
                                    HomeCard(homeCard: homeCard, geo: geo.size.width)
                                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            }
                      }
```

This is my List code in the second View:

```
 List {
    ForEach(HttpResponseHolder.shared.exoplanets.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.pl_name.contains(searchText) }), id: \.self) { exoplanet in
     
        NavigationLink(destination: ExoplanetDetailView(exoplanet: exoplanet)) {

                            ExoplanetCard(exoplanet: exoplanet)

                       }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                      }.listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                       .padding(.trailing, -15) 
                       .padding(.leading, 2)
                       .padding(.top, 2)
                       .padding(.bottom, 2)
                      }.id(UUID())
```

Is that a SwiftUI bug that can't handle many elements in a List?

**UPDATE**

ExoplanetCard's body

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22.0)
                .opacity(0.8)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 31/255, green: 40/255, blue: 45/255))
            
            HStack(alignment:.center, spacing: 20, content: {
                Spacer()
                imageForExoplanet(exoplanet: exoplanet)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment:.center)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .opacity(0.9)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                
                Divider()
                
                VStack(spacing:5) {
                    Text(exoplanet.pl_name)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                    
                    planetTypeTextReturner(exoplanet: exoplanet)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.body)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                }
                
                Spacer()
            })
        }
    }
```

ExoplanetDetailView is just an empty view so far.

**EDIT 2**

So by making my data model conforming to Identifiable e by giving it an id property of type UUID() and removing the id:.self the performance are now better. Still not perfect but at least improved a bit.

Comment: There might be many reasons, it needs to debug... first of all remove `.id(UUID())`, then it needs to review if init of `ExoplanetCard` and `ExoplanetDetailView` are not heavy, and of course remove filter from `ForEach` and make it out of rendering context.

Comment: @Asperi I did the following tests: 1. Removed .id(UUID()) 2. Removed .filter. but it is still slow. I will update my post to include ExoplanetCard and ExoplanetDetailView,